# Call API on React app start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working in a React app, at the start of the application I need to make a GET request to a external API that give me some settings, this call I need to make it also when the user login and logout of the system. Currently I have that implemented, now I am not sure where should I call it.

I have a  component, and inside I have the method `ComponentWillReceiveProps` there I am calling the request, however it's calling many many times and this is not what I want. So, which method os the proper to call it? depending of the answer of the API some of the components will be rendered or not. Thank you

Comment: any time props change, ComponentWillReceiveProps is called so thats what causing the multiple calls to the api, one of the mount methods would work. this a a good article. http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this for example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onLoad: (payload ) => {
    dispatch({ type: APP_LOAD, payload});}  
});

class App extends React.Component {
 componentWillMount() {
   this.props.onLoad(Promise.all([reduxagent.get.all()]));
 }
}
```

Here you may load your props within promise  right after application starts.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 7):

I would call the external API in `componentDidMount`, since it's the recommended place to perform side effects ([source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)).

Once you get the data, you can store it in the component state (or redux, if you have that). And then decide what to render in the `render` method based on the state.

Example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    callExternalApi().then(data => {
      this.setState({
        data: data,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (data === 'render div') {
      return <div />;
    }
    return <span />;
  }
}
```